# Bokeh y axis ticks in bits and have it scale from an SI magnitude perspective

Tags: python, bokeh

First question here so conscious my approach may not be spot on but fingers crossed!

I'm looking to plot bits per second from a pandas DataFrame on a Bokeh Y axis (against time on the x axis) and whilst I can use the PrintfTickFormatter to adjust my ticks manually, they don't scale in the way I've implemented it:

```
p.yaxis[0].formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format="%3f M")
```

My raw data is in bytes, so I convert this in my DataFrame before graphing to bits (after calculating the diff between current and previous bytes and converting to bits, and then dividing in this instance by 600 to get a per-second value) but often my data is Megabits or Gigabits so I don't really want to be plotting in bits as it becomes incomprehensible and I don't really want to manually adjust as above using PrintfTickFormatter as I have to divide the CumulbitsPerSecond by the relevant unit prior to plotting (unless I can somehow scale and interpret SI units within this formatter or implement some sort of y axis for loop based on the plotted values).

For instance here's an example DataFrame:

```
                            CumulativeBytes  CumulBytesDiff  CumulbitsDiff  CumulbitsPerSecond
DateTime
2020-12-05 09:40:03.175453          1000000             NaN            NaN                 NaN
2020-12-05 09:50:03.175453          3000000       2000000.0     16000000.0        26666.666667
2020-12-05 10:00:03.175453          4000000       1000000.0      8000000.0        13333.333333
2020-12-05 10:10:03.175453          7000000       3000000.0     24000000.0        40000.000000
2020-12-05 10:20:03.175453          8000000       1000000.0      8000000.0        13333.333333
2020-12-05 10:30:03.175453          9200000       1200000.0      9600000.0        16000.000000
2020-12-05 10:40:03.175453         10600000       1400000.0     11200000.0        18666.666667
```

What I'm looking for is exactly what the NumeralTickFormatter Byte y tick axis adjuster would do:

```
p.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.0b")
```

...but for bits. Maybe FuncTickFormatter might help but I can't get my head around how I would implement it in python3.6 Bokeh 2.2.3.

Example code to plot the above DataFrame if named df would be as follows:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, NumeralTickFormatter, PrintfTickFormatter

output_file('stackoverflowq.html')

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")

p.line(x='DateTime', y='CumulbitsPerSecond', color='blue', source=df)

# Only allows me to reference bytes when I need to plot bits
#p.yaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.0b")

# Requires manual adjustment of bits to Kilobits in the instance with the dataframe above
#p.yaxis[0].formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format="%3f Kbps")

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date Time'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'bits per second'

show(p)
```

Can anyone please advise? Happy to provide the DataFrame code too but hopefully this is sufficient.

Output plot is as below and in this instance I would want the Y axis ticks to show as Kb or Kbps and if the bit values were in the megabit region then as Mb or Mbps etc.

[image: bokeh_plot]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I suggest you post some sample code of something you've tried (along with some sample data) – you'll be more likely to get a helpful response.

Comment: Hi C.Braun! Thank you for the readability edits on the capital letter at the start at altering the code snippets. I'll look to edit the query with some example code and maybe an example plot, struggling to keep it brief though. Maybe I just need to reword the question somehow to "How can I plot bits on the y-axis in a scalar fashion matching SI units?" and leave it at that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you are lookin for something like this:

```
p.yaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code='''if (tick < 1000){
                                                  return (tick) + ' ' + 'BpS'
                                              }
                                              else if (tick < 1000000){
                                                  return (tick/1000) + ' ' + 'KiBpS'
                                              }
                                              else{
                                                  return (tick/1000000) + ' ' + 'MBpS'
                                                }'''
                                     )
```

This is a JavaScript solution to your question.

**Minimal Example**

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FuncTickFormatter
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({'BitsPerSeconde': [26, 13333, 40000, 1333300, 16666]})
p = figure()

p.line(x='index', y='BitsPerSeconde', color='blue', source=df)
p.yaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code='''if (tick < 1000){return (tick) + ' ' + 'BpS'}
                                              else if (tick < 1000000){
                                                  return (tick/1000) + ' ' + 'KiBpS'
                                                  }
                                              else{
                                                  return (tick/1000000) + ' ' + 'MBpS'
                                                }'''
                                     )
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'bits per second'
show(p)
```

This is the output.
[image]

Comment: Hi mosc9575 - thank you very much for this! I've been able to use/adapt (basically just dropping the use of a capital B to avoid interpretation as bytes) that as required so I appreciate it! 
In terms of processing time to compute the ticks using Javascript, would you say that this adds much overhead (perhaps difficult to quantify much but say if I've 50 lines each with 144 values to plot)? Someone suggested and then deleted, using a preprocessing approach whereby I calculate a string based on the df.max() values in the DataFrame, though I fear this method would prevent scaling between units.